# People Reached hover text partially hidden by nav bar

Tags: bug

The hover text for your 'people reached' is partially hidden by the new nav bar.

[image: impact]

Using Chrome:
     Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Comment: I believe that was asked recently.